# Google Maps API: Is there a way to find Segment information on a Route between 2 places

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, directions, google-directions-api

Google Maps API
Is there a way to find Segment information on a Route between 2 places

I have 2 places/addresses/latlong.
I am looking for the direction between the two.
For this direction, I need type information about the segment:

- Is it a road
- Is it a highway
- Is it a bridge
- ...

Comment: You need input, (sorting it too) a pathfinding algorithm, and output.

Comment: @FailingCoder The Google Maps API already builds the direction between the two places.
But it gives me a set of legs, composed of a set of steps... but the lowest segment only has the distance, starting and ending points. Nothing else.
I'm looking for more information about this segment

Comment: You can specify in a request to avoid highways, but other than that; what you want isn't currently offered by Google on the Directions API. You could make a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

## Follow the link , i hope it is useful for you.

https://medium.com/@trientran/android-working-with-google-maps-and-directions-api-44765433f19?